# Cannot install ruby-1.9.2 in Mac OSX 10.8.1 due to symlink error

Tags: ruby, macos, gcc, installation, rvm

First, I tried the common rvm install.

rvm install 1.9.2

However, the following error was shown:

```
The provided compiler '/usr/bin/gcc' is LLVM based, it is not yet fully supported by ruby and gems, please read `rvm requirements`.
```

Then I run

```
rvm requirements
```

and find these following part of output useful

```
Right now Ruby requires gcc to compile, but Xcode 4.2 and later no longer ship with gcc. Instead they ship with llvm-gcc (to which gcc is a symlink) and clang, neither of which are supported for building Ruby. Xcode 4.1 was the last version to ship gcc, which was /usr/bin/gcc-4.2.

Xcode 4.1 and earlier:
- Ruby will build fine.

Xcode 4.2 and later (including Command Line Tools for Xcode):
- If you have gcc-4.2 (and friends) from an earlier Xcode version, Ruby will build fine.
- If you don't have gcc-4.2, you have two options to get it:
 * Install apple-gcc42 from Homebrew
 * Install osx-gcc-installer

Homebrew:
If you are using Homebrew, you can install the apple-gcc42 and required libraries from homebrew/dupes:
 brew update
 brew tap homebrew/dupes
 brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42 
 rvm pkg install openssl

This can live side by side with an existing Xcode 4.2+ install or Command Line Tools for Xcode.
```

so I tried:

```
brew update
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42
```

However, I got the following error

```
Warning: Could not link apple-gcc42. Unlinking...
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link apple-gcc42'
==> Summary
/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3: 104 files, 75M, built in 23 seconds
kanitw:shell.venturelab.com kanitw$ brew link apple-gcc42
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3... Warning: Could not link apple-gcc42. Unlinking...
Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/include/gcc
/usr/local/include is not writable. You should change its permissions.
```

What would be my best solution?  I kinda remember from somewhere that I should not use sudo with brew since I will mess up the whole installation.

Comment: Try `sudo brew install apple-gcc42`.

Comment: no, don't try that. That's not the idea of homebrew!

Answer (score 4):

You can change /usr/local directory owner

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
```

But, if you have mysql installed, you mast fix its owner

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql
```

Answer (score 3):

You should run `brew doctor` and then change the permissions accordingly. There might be other issues.

Comment: Unfortunately, `brew doctor` doesn't help very much. It just told me to run `brew link` on apple-gcc42 which is precisely the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the permissions of your `/usr/local` directory and try again.