# Installing ruby 1.9.3 on Mac OSX 10.8.2

Tags: ruby, macos

I am trying to install Ruby on my new Mac, but I'm having some issues, and was wondering if anyone can help?

The main error is:

```
Right now Ruby requires gcc to compile, but Xcode 4.2 and later no longer ship with gcc.
Instead they ship with llvm-gcc (to which gcc is a symlink) and clang, neither of which are
supported for building Ruby. Xcode 4.1 was the last version to ship gcc, which was
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2.
```

I tried to solve the error using the advice in this post "[Cannot install ruby-1.9.2 in Mac OSX 10.8.1 due to symlink error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578220/cannot-install-ruby-1-9-2-in-mac-osx-10-8-1-due-to-symlink-error)", but even after installing gcc via homebrew, I still get the aforementioned error.

When I type `gcc - v`, I get the following message:

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~67/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~67/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

Lastly, I checked my /usr/bin folder, and I see a gcc-4.2 unix executable file that is about 104KB. Is this what I should have?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604119/install-ruby-with-mountain-lion-xcode-4-5-and-rvm

Comment: Thank you! I followed their instruction, and installed gcc (i think), but it still doesn't work

Comment: Are you installing ruby via homebrew, or making it on your own? I've installed ruby-1.9.3 with homebrew with no issues.

Comment: I'm using RVM, and everytime I try rvm -install 1.9.3, they can't find gcc

Comment: I installed 1.9.3 using http://jewelrybox.unfiniti.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to let `rvm` know which `gcc` to use:

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3
```

Or, if you want to use the Homebrew-installed `gcc`:

```
CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3
```

It depends on where the `gcc-4.2` interpreter is.

Two alternatives:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

Or use [`ruby-build`](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build).

**EDIT September 7, 2013**: Another alternative that I'm liking quite a lot for installing Rubies is [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install). It's in the spirit of the same author's [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby). Simple and gets the job done well.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the reputation yet to make a comment but i just wanted to note that based on Telemachus comment this worked for me 
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang

im running os x 10.8.4

Answer (score 0):

you should install xcode command line tool first, you can find in xcode preferences' download tab.

[image]

then install homebrew, it's a package manager like yum in centos, you can use that to install git etc.

then install rvm, then use `rvm install ruby`.

Comment: He was able to install `gcc` with Homebrew. I'm pretty sure he has the Command Line Tools - otherwise, that wouldn't have been possible.